# Error on creating word, letter, character count function n findword, findchar

Tags: c++, character, cpu-word, letters

I cant get this program to compile. I get an error by the auto start and auto end. That there is no name a type. Also am trying to get `findword` and `findchar` in this program to work. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    string allWords;

    int lineCharacterCount = 0;

    int maxCharacterCount = 60;

    int charactersRemaining = 0;

    string delimiter = " ";

    string word;

    string sentense;

    int remainder = 0;

    getline(cin, allWords);

    auto start = 0U;
    auto end = allWords.find(delimiter);
    while (end != string::npos)
    {
        word = allWords.substr(start, end - start);

        if (((word.length() + 1) + lineCharacterCount) < maxCharacterCount)
        {
            sentense.append(word);
            sentense.append(" ");
            lineCharacterCount += word.length() + 1;

            start = end + delimiter.length();
            end = allWords.find(delimiter, start);
        }
        else
        {
            word = allWords.substr(start, end - start);

            // Note to myself: Find how many characters are remaining to reach maxCharacterCount minus 1 for the hyphen
            charactersRemaining = (maxCharacterCount - lineCharacterCount) - 1;
            if ((word.length() - charactersRemaining) > 0)
            {
                sentense.append(word.substr(0, charactersRemaining));
                sentense.append("-");
                remainder += 1;
            }

            cout << sentense << endl;
            sentense = "";
            lineCharacterCount = 0;

            if (remainder)
            {
                sentense.append(word.substr(charactersRemaining, string::npos));
                sentense.append(" ");
                lineCharacterCount += word.length() + 1;
                remainder = 0;
            }

            start = end + delimiter.length();
            end = allWords.find(delimiter, start);
        }
    }

    word = allWords.substr(start, end - start);
    sentense.append(word);

    cout << sentense << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you using c++ 11 compiler ?

Comment: i believe so, i am

Comment: It definitely looks as if you're compiling for the C++03 standard. With g++ add option `-std=c++11`, or `-std=c++14` if the version you have supports it. To get more detailed help please include **the relevant information** such as your compiler and verision, the command you use the build (and any relevant environment variables or other configuration of the compiler), and the diagostic you get quoted verbatim.

Comment: Removed tag from title and improved formatiting

Answer (score 0):

set the compiler flags  -std=c++11